# More efficient than a doubly-nested ArrayList?

Tags: java, performance, list, data-structures, hashmap

I am building a Java back-end component that processes a moderate volume of data every day. We have a POJO, let's call it `Widget`, that has about 10 properties on it. My software must process groups of `Widget` lists: essentially there are other processes (completely different systems) that put together their own `List<Widget>`, and then send them to my software. My software actually receives a wrapper POJO that looks like this:

```
public class Payload {
    private List<Widget> widgets; // <-- what I want
    private String guid; // GUID; my software doesn't need this
    private boolean fizz; // again, my software doesn't need this
    ... many other properties that I don't care about
}
```

My software aggregates all these `List<Widget>`, each created by different systems, and then process them together in one big batch.

I have tentatively chose `ArrayList<ArrayList<Widget>>` as the data structure for holding this batch of `Widget` lists. There will be about 500,000 groups of `List<Widget>` (the outer `ArrayList`), and each `List<Widget>` will have about 5 `Widget`s each; for a grand total of ~2.5 million `Widget`s in the inner `ArrayList`.

At a recent code review, some tech leads told me I had chosen the wrong data structure for this batch o' widgets. They told me I should have used `HashMap<String,List<Widget>>`, because its more efficient and easier to work with. The hashmap key is a GUID contained in the `Payload` that my software is given. Not that I need the GUID for any reason, it just serves as a key to keep the ~500,000 `List<Widget>` separate - which I do need to do.

This got me thinking: who's right?!? The only operations we're doing on this data structure are "adds" (in the case of `ArrayList`, just adding a `Widget` or a `List<Widget>` via `add(...)`) and then "reads" (inside my software I have to iterate through every `Widget` and inspect it for stuff. With my nested `ArrayList` the gist of it is:

```
for(List<Widget> widgetList : myDoublyNestedArrayOfWidgets) {
    for(Widget widget : widgetList) {
        ...
    }
}
```

These are the only operations we need: add the disparate `List<Widget>`s to some big "batch" data structure, and then at a later time, inspect all of them and do stuff with each `Widget`. This software runs on some beefed up servers with lots of memory and processing power.

So I ask: **Is `ArrayList<ArrayList<Widget>>` the right choice, `HashMap<String,List<Widget>>`, or something else... and why?

Comment: I feel that you're saying a lot of stuff that isn't required to answer the core question. Try to think of it as listing facts rather than telling a story.

Comment: If you process everything together, could you just use an `ArrayList<Widget>` and add Widget`s to your main list as they come in?  Also, do you need all 500k sets before you start processing, or could you handle each little list as it comes in and just store the results.  Spawning a thread that handles each little list and then tosses the list once it's done could be a lot more memory efficient

Comment: On a side note, your username made me laugh =)

Comment: Is the order of processing important? ie. do you want to process older batches first? If so, a guid keyed Map would ruin this ordering (unless you used a TreeMap and can guarantee that guids are in order)

Comment: @Dukeling I agree in part, however if you skip to the end the question is set out fairly clearly. might benefit from a 'TL;DR' heading but I found the extra context helpful personally.

Comment: I think a LinkedList is probably better than an ArrayList but outside of that, I think a List based implementation is correct. Or more accurately, a LinkedList<ArrayList<Widget>> assuming you know the exact size of the ArrayList content at initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I ask: Is `ArrayList<ArrayList<Widget>>` the right choice, `HashMap<String,List<Widget>>`, or something else...and why?

At the very end, what matters is that your software solves the problem it is supposed to solve.

A HashMap is more expensive than an ArrayList, and if you don't need to access the data via a key, the ArrayList is more probably the best choice.
Also the code you need to write to do your processing seems more simple and efficient while using an ArrayList.

By the way, having `ArrayList<ArrayList<Widget>>`, or `HashMap<String,List<Widget>>` smells a little bit. Maybe what you are modeling is a `ArrayList<WidgetGroup>` and a `WidgetGroup` contains a `List<Widget>` (with all other properties that -at the moment- you may not need). But, if your WidgetGroup just contains an ArrayList, don't introduce this new class (keep it simpler).

> This got me thinking: who's right?!?

Between your solution and your peer reviewer's, I personally strongly prefer yours.

But, you may keep this for yourself and follow the "tech leads". If this is their role, it's their decision that matters and their responsibility to provide those choices. (And the guy paying your checks is always right)

Answer (score 2):

There's a noun that you keep using, but is missing from your data model: **Batch**.
If you really care about keeping them in their batches, and keeping your code readable, then encapsulate them in a Batch class:

```
class Batch {
    String guid;
    List<Widget> widgets;
}
```

And, if you don't care about batches, then could you just flatten them all into a single `List<Widget>`?

Answer (score 1):

A hash map is not more efficient or easier to work with than an array list. The change could be justified if at some point you do need to look up a batch by its GUID key.

A hash map is less efficient than an array list because resizing it means having to re-evaluate the hash codes and re-distribute the data into fairly random memory locations. Resizing an array on the other hand copies the content from the old array to the new linearly, which is much friendlier for the CPU cache.

A hash map is not easier to work with, either. To access the entries you have to go through the map's entry set, which breaks the [law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an embedded (in-core) database is what you finally want. Another possibility would be something like JavaSpaces/NoSQL, decoupling delivery and processing. Depends.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it's clear that you are doing these things.

1. *Read from your data.*
2. *Add more widgets.*

Question arises how will changing your data structure from `ArrayList<ArrayList<Widget>> to HashMap<String,List<Widget>>` affect above two activities.

**1) Read** : you have grouped them into 4 groups, so using `hashmap` you will store your groups using hashing which really don't make sense for small set of data(groups in your case) so no need to use hashmap here.

**2) Adding more widgets** : You will access List to which you are going to add, so again same your are down to reading. It won't hurt to use  `ArrayListObj.get(index)`.

Now Using `ArrayList` will always read `widgets` in sequence. Which will not be done using `Hashmap`, but anyways I don't think that is your concern or is it? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hashmap would be more efficient if you had to access the inner lists randomly and the code using a hashmap *looks* more elegant to reviewers who break out in hives when they see nested loops.  But, if you have to iterate through and visit every node, you won't do better than On^2.  You could stuff them in a DB, but that doesn't gain you anything other than complexity.  It's more elegant, like the hashmap.  Of course, all this assumes you have the memory to hold all 2.5 million Widgets at once.  If you have to page it, then some sort of DB SQL or NoSQL would probably be better.